# Hagala for a new pot

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha, sources-mekorot

I know that there is a halakhic necessity to tovel a new pot.  However, has anyone ever heard of the halakhic necessity to do hagala on a new pot?
Reason for asking [was this](http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/2010/12/eida-halts-hechsher-on-sultam-pots/).

Comment: btw, I would like to use this opportunity to say Sultam pots are fantastic! We have a whole set and they are still in great shape after 7 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Israel and not In America they Have this Minhag, because of the treatment used while making the Pot for certain types of metal including steel and aluminum are rolled out, the rollers are smeared with animal fat. For an extensive answer see [HERE](http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/2011/01/kashering-new-pots/#more-4335)

Comment: And in certain cases, I'd heard that the Star-K contacted a Muslim society about this problem, who had enough clout to get the manufacturer to switch.

Comment: Some cast-iron or wrought-iron (not stainless) pots come "preseasoned", i.e. some oil has been baked into them to make them stick-resistant.  I've seen Lodge claim that they're using OU-kosher oil (http://www.lodgemfg.com/use-care-help.asp#5); interesting question for Pesach, but the minute quantity of shemen kitniyos from before Pesach would certainly be batel.

Comment: "Would certainly be batel" is an assumption that, even if Halachically sound, tends to not hold in the world of Pesach certification.

Comment: That is Reb MOshe Opinion not shared by Rab Eliyashiv though.

Comment: @SimchasTorah, which part does R' Elyashiv disagree about?  Disregarding the shemen kitniyos aspect -- I thought everyone holds that kitniyos is batel b'rov.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was (is?) a practice to glaze new aluminium pots with non-Kosher fats before selling them. Hacham Ovadia (Yabia Omer Y"D 6:10) ruled that such pots **do not require** hag'alah, because the glaze carries has no taste, and may be used **lechatechila** without hag'alah.